# Algorithm to find a path connecting given nodes in a graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

Suppose I have $n$ nodes in a graph and I identify $x$ nodes in the graph (where $x < n$). I would like to find a path to connect all those $x$ nodes I have identified. Is there any algorithm for such a scenario?

Comment: If $x = n$ then this sounds a lot like the NP-complete problem Hamiltonian Path. The case $x = n-1$ doesn't sound too much easier. Perhaps you should make clear what you mean by a *path* in this context.

Comment: I'm looking at a possibility to connect those x nodes resulting in a subgraph. x = n-1 in this case.

Comment: So it's more like spanning tree or Steiner tree.

Comment: I believe Steiner tree will solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is known as the [Steiner tree problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem). While this problem is NP-complete, it has efficient constant-factor approximation algorithms.